# jQuery using append with effects

Tags: jquery, animation, append, effects, show

How can I use `.append()` with effects like `show('slow')`

Having effects on `append` doesn't seem to work at all, and it give the same result as normal `show()`. No transitions, no animations.

How can I append one div to another, and have a `slideDown` or `show('slow')` effect on it?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Having effects on append won't work because the content the browser displays is updated as soon as the div is appended. So, to combine Mark B's and Steerpike's answers:

Style the div you're appending as hidden before you actually append it. You can do it with inline or external CSS script, or just create the div as

```
<div id="new_div" style="display: none;"> ... </div>
```

*Then* you can chain effects to your append ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/acwPR/)):

```
$('#new_div').appendTo('#original_div').show('slow');
```

Or ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/C2S8k)):

```
var $new = $('#new_div');
$('#original_div').append($new);
$new.show('slow');
```

Comment: was probably the inline style, adding a css class like "hidden" which equates to display: none is .. "classier" (baddoom tsh) ;)

Comment: This won't work. When you use append, it will return the original_div not the newly appended element. So you are actually calling show on the container.

Comment: @Vic as it happens `.append()` doesn't even take a selector string. The idea's still correct though. Thanks, updated.

Comment: The demo works perfectly, but it assumes the content exists - so it won't work if you are generating the content, eg. pulling an image's alt content to create a title or div...

Answer (score 129):

The essence is this:

1. You're calling 'append' on the parent
2. but you want to call 'show' on the new child

This works for me:

```
var new_item = $('<p>hello</p>').hide();
parent.append(new_item);
new_item.show('normal');
```

or:

```
$('<p>hello</p>').hide().appendTo(parent).show('normal');
```

Comment: I've tried both of these ways and it doesn't work.  There is no smooth sliding effect on the appended content.

Comment: `'normal'` is not a proper string for speed. leave it blank for no transition (shows up immediately). use string `'fast'` for 200ms or `'slow'` for 600ms. or type any number like `$("element").show(747)` (= 747ms) to define own speed. see the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/show/) and look for animation / duration.

Comment: With slide effect: 
 `element.slideUp("slow", function(){
  element.appendTo(parent).hide();
  element.slideDown();
 });`

Comment: I like keeping the hide part out of the template

Answer (score 27):

Another way when working with incoming data (like from an ajax call):

```
var new_div = $(data).hide();
$('#old_div').append(new_div);
new_div.slideDown();
```

Answer (score 18):

Something like:

```
$('#test').append('<div id="newdiv">Hello</div>').hide().show('slow');
```

should do it?

Edit: sorry, mistake in code and took Matt's suggestion on board too.

Comment: Not sure if that would do what he wants, but if so, you'd chain the functions: `$('#divid').append('#newdiv').hide().show('slow')`.

Comment: It does work; the #newdiv bit is wrong though and you're right, you can chain them. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: This is the best answer one line clean and does what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 8):

When you append to the div, **hide it** and **show it** with the argument `"slow"`.

```
$("#img_container").append(first_div).hide().show('slow');
```

Comment: The hide and show event applies to the #img_container and not on the first_div, you should use appendTo

Answer (score 4):

Set the appended div to be hidden initially through css `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 3):

I was in need of a similar kind of solution, wanted to add data on a wall like facebook, when posted,use `prepend()` to add the latest post on top, thought might be useful for others..

```
$("#statusupdate").submit( function () {    
          $.post(
           'ajax.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){

                $("#box").prepend($(data).fadeIn('slow'));                  
                $("#status").val('');
            }
          );
           event.preventDefault();   
        });
```

the code in ajax.php is

```
if (isset($_POST))
{

    $feed = $_POST['feed'];
    echo "<p id=\"result\" style=\"width:200px;height:50px;background-color:lightgray;display:none;\">$feed</p>";


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact need in my final project where I appended the element with style `display: none;` and added an id to it. In the second line of JQuery, I added `$('#myid').show('slow');`.

```js
$(document).on('click','#trigger',function(){
  $('#container').append("<label id='newLabel' style='display:none;' class='btn btn-light'>New Element</label>");
  $('#newLabel').show('slow');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="container" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-light">Old element</label>
</div>
<button id="trigger" class="btn btn-info">Click to see effect</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply hide, append, then show, like this:

```
<div id="parent1" style="  width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: yellow;">
    <div id="child" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>


<div id="parent2" style="  width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;">
</div>

<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="move">

<script>
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        $('#child').hide(1000, function(){
            $('#parent2').append($('#child'));
            $('#child').show(1000);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show smooth if you use Animation. 
In style just add "animation: show 1s" and the whole appearance discribe in keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
$("div.which-stores-content").append("<div class="content">Content</div>);
$("div.content").hide().show("fast");
```

you can adjust your css with visibility:hidden -> visibility:visible and adjust the transitions etc transition: visibility 1.0s;