# Split a string by the first hyphen in the string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I know the split routine of JavaScript. I've a string in this pattern `Employee - John Smith - Director`.

I want to split it on the base of first hyphen using JavaScript and it'll seem like:

Source: `Employee`
Sub: `John Smith - Director`

Comment: probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character

Comment: use match instead of split https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/23

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression:

```
b = "Employee - John Smith - Director"
c = b.split(/\s-\s(.*)/g)
c    
["Employee", "John Smith - Director", ""]
```

So you have in `c[0]` the first word and in `c[1]` the rest.

Comment: Why it returns another empty element at the end of the array?

Answer (score 2):

you can do like

```
var str = "Employee - John Smith - Director "  
var s=str.split("-");
s.shift() ;
s.join("-");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Employee - John Smith - Director "  
str.split("-",1)
```

Then to split other use this link: [How can I split a long string in two at the nth space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440066/how-can-i-split-a-long-string-in-two-at-the-nth-space)

Comment: This returns "Employee " and nothing else. Did you test your code? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Parameters

Comment: Yes, I'm doing. here is my code var res = str.split(" - ", 1);

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but I wasn't super satisfied with the existing answers. So here is my staight-forward and easy-to-read solution:

```js
const splitAtFirstOccurence = (string, pattern) => {
  const index = string.indexOf(pattern);
  return [string.slice(0, index), string.slice(index + pattern.length)];
}

console.log(splitAtFirstOccurence('Employee - John Smith - Director', ' - '));
// ["Employee", "John Smith - Director"]
```