# Making text disappear letter by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery development and I want to ask what is the most simple way of making html text slowly disappear letter by letter using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11665782/1048572. You need the same code structure, only that you remove elements instead of appending them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I got even more curious, I think I created the exact one that you are looking for,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DbknZ/3/

```
$(function() {
  var $test = $('#test');
  var initText = $.trim($test.text()), ptr = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var ln = $.trim($test.find('.trans').text().length);
    if (ln == initText.length) {
        $test.empty();
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    $('#test').html(function() {    

        return $('<span>').addClass('removeMe')
            .html(initText.substring(ptr++ , ptr))
            .before($('<span>').addClass('trans').
                   html(initText.substring(0 , ptr-1)))
            .after(initText.substring(ptr));
    }).find('span.removeMe').animate({'opacity': 0}, 10);

  }, 20);
});
```

---

I just got curious and wrote a small thing for you.. which could be a starter..

Basically it is a timer which removes letter by letter.. See below.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TTv7L/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
   This is a test page to demonstrate text disapper letter by letter
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var $test = $('#test');
    var timer = setInterval( function () {
        var ln = $test.text().length;
        if (ln == 0) clearInterval(timer);

        $('#test').text(function (i, v) {
            return v.substring(1);
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: it's not disapearing, it's running text.

Comment: @GomatoX It is a starter.. and it is not running text.. it removes the text

Comment: Wow, that really looks nice! But now I'm sad as I don't have an occasion to use jQuery and/or your solution :(

Comment: The final result looks like it's running, but it's maby the start for question owner

Comment: @GomatoX True.. I have updated my demo to fade out (disapper) http://jsfiddle.net/DbknZ/3/