# Using JQuery Deferred and Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to use deferred and promise to chain an animation.

The first animation is a type writer plugin, using https://github.com/stephband/jticker/blob/master/js/jquery.jticker.js.
The second is a function that contains other animations.

What I want to do is run the first animation and when the animation is completed, run the second.

```
 $(function () {            
        var ticker =setTimeout(runTicker(), 8000);           
        $.when(ticker).done(function(){
            setTimeout(Other(),16000)});
    });

  function runTicker() {
        $("#ticker").ticker({
            cursorList: " ",
            rate: 50,
            delay: 18000
        }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");
    }
```

I have tried numerous examples of deferred, but still can't get it.

I finally cleared all the examples in order to get the ticker working again.

How would I use deferred and promise to run the Other() function?

Thank you

Comment: What ticker plugin do you use? Please link to its API docs.

Comment: I am uploading the plugin now, but I got it at  http://www.thepixelart.com/create-a-typing-text-effect-using-jquery/
Thanks again

Comment: It's now on-line at http://styliststudioinc.com/jquery.jticker.js

Comment: also, this is the page I've been working on. http://styliststudioinc.com/start.html  I have tried so many different things, my mind is scrambled.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The plugins does not seem to offer a callback for its animation end, you might want to have a look at [my own solution (simple but fast)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11665782/1048572) which can easily be converted to return a Promise. Yet it does not support play- and stop-events, but I don't think you would need them anyway.

Comment: When I was searching for help, I saw your example. I wish I knew jQuery like you, but as you age it takes a while to learn things. I've been watching the learndevnow videos, but I still don't understand how to get this to work.  I've already spent about a week trying to figure this out. This application isn't released yet, but at this rate, it never will be:-(
Do you offer a paid service that could help me figure this out?

Comment: I do have an event that stops the runTicker 
 function stopRunTicker() {
            jQuery(".stop").click(function () {
                jQuery("#ticker").trigger("stop");
                return false;
            });
        }

Comment: Sorry, I can only offer this free service here :-) As you need the stop'n'go feature and really can't figure out the timeout end in that script (must be somewhere in `ticker` or `tape`), I might rewrite my snippet to integrate with jQuery (it currently does not use a single line of jQuery).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19557/discussion-between-sheri-trager-and-bergi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how to solve your actual problem with a proper callback-based solution (not enough information on the Ticker plugin you use), but I can explain what goes wrong in your current code:

```
var ticker = setTimeout(runTicker(), 8000);
```

Don't call `runTicker` immediately. What you want is to pass the function itself - not the result of its invocation - into [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). A [plain integer] number will be returned and is assigned to `ticker`. It can be used for identifying the timeout when aborting it via [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) - and nowhere else.

```
$.when(ticker)...
```

creates a new Deferred now. Have a look at [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/): It will combine Deferred objects with each other and create immediately-resolved Promises for *any other values* - like numbers. Therefore, your `done` callback is also called immidiately, and again you make the mistake with executing `Other` instead of passing it into `setTimeout`.

---

As the plugin you used seems very limited in regard to callbacks, I've written my own now (just for fun :-). It adapts my solution from [this former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665782/1048572) which uses pure DOM methods quite elegantly. It is written as a standard jQuery plugin, even favours `stop` and `go` methods and - most important - integrates well in the [jQuery `fx` queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058158/1048572). That means you will be able to use it exactly like [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) regarding callbacks and chaining, and if you want to work with Deferreds you can invoke the [`promise()` method](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to get a Promise for the queue's end. Example call:

```
$('#ticker').fadeOut().delay(2000).typewriter({framerate:1000/30}, function() {
    // the typewriter effect has just ended
}). ... .promise().done(function() {
    // effect queue has ended - start Other()
});

jQuery(".stop").click($.fn.typewriter.bind($("#ticker"), "stop"));
```

### → [Code at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/T5kZM/45/)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` obviously will not return a jQuery *Deferred object*, its a native Javascript method here. You need to re-write it like so:

```
function runTicker() {
    return jQuery.Deferred(function( promise ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#ticker").ticker({
                cursorList: " ",
                rate: 50,
                delay: 18000
            }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");

            promise.resolve();
        }, 8000);
    }).promise();
}
```

And then you can call it like

```
var ticker = runTicker();

jQuery.when( ticker ).done(function() {
    setTimeout(Other,16000)});
});
```

Comment: I tried the 
     function runTicker() {
            return jQuery.Deferred(function (promise) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#ticker").ticker({
                        cursorList: " ",
                        rate: 50,
                        delay: 18000
                    }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");

                    promise.resolve();
                }, 8000);
            }).promise();
        }
and called it as you said, but the runTicker didn't run.
Thanks for your help