# Why does this function no longer work in jquery 1.9.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've decided to update all my jquery to work with jquery 1.9.1 but I can find out why this script has stopped working. Works fine in all other jquery versions.

```
// Typewriter function
$.fn.Typewriter = function Typewriter(opts) {
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            animDelay: 50
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    var objDiv = document.getElementById(settings.div);
    $.each(settings.text, function (i, letter) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.html($this.html() + (letter != '\n' ? letter : '<br />'));

            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }, settings.animDelay * i);
    });
};

// Call with 
// $('#divID').Typewriter({animDelay: 10,text: 'text to animate', div: 'divID'});

$('#outputDiv').Typewriter({
    animDelay: 10,
    text: 'Why does this not work in jquery 1.9.1? :( ',
    div: 'outputDiv'
});
```

Js fiddle included below

http://jsfiddle.net/T2AJ5/

EDIT:

Using the chrome development tool I get a error in the console reading:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '42' in Why
>   does this not work in jquery 1.9.1? :(

Comment: Please elaborate on "stopped working". Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Does your computer catch on fire?

Comment: Nothing happens, calling the function doesn't output anything to outputDiv

Comment: Are you passing a string to `$.each`?

Comment: It's failing because you passed text into $.each rather than an object or an array. If you use methods the way they are documented, you won't run into as many issues on upgrades to the library. Split the string before passing it into $.each.

Comment: @KevinB sounds like an answer; I can confirm the behavior that `each` use to work on strings and 1.9 broke it.

Comment: Yeah, try this http://jsfiddle.net/TmLrC/ with different versions of jQuery set - it seemed to work pre-1.9

Comment: Yep, definitely changed in 1.9. Same problem was raised, but classified as not a bug by JQ: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13362.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One does not use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop over strings. I doubt it worked properly before. For a quick fix, change it to `settings.text.split('')`.

Btw, appending to `innerHTML` can be [troublesome](http://return-true.com/2012/01/html-compatible-jquery-typewriter/). Better use the [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665782/1048572), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391131/1048572) for that callback hell wrapped in a jQuery plugin :-)

Comment: Thank you for the help Bergi and Kevin