# Automatically update table

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

I have a PHP script render a beautiful series of div elements from MySQL info, now I want it to update dynamically and add new divs as new fields in MySQL are added.

```
window.setInterval(function() {

         $.get('tableup.php', function(balance) {
             $('.containerDiv').html(balance);
         });

    }, 60000*0.1);
```

First question is how do I add the divs to the top of the container div with a fade effect?
Second question is how do I know which divs to return in tableup.php? I already have the dates of every field saved, would passing them to the tableup, parsing them, then running a proper query on the database work? How do I save the date client side? The format is like this `2012-11-17 13:26:31`

Comment: Re: the first question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520178/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Use something like

```
$('.containerDiv').prepend(balance).fadeIn('slow');
```

Be sure to set the "incoming" div's as `display: none` in your css, so you don't see a flash.

**Question 2:**

Sure, save the date as timestamp or in your format in a variable and just pass it to the script

```
var time = '2012-11-17 13:26:31';

window.setInterval(function() {

         $.get('tableup.php', { lastTime: time }, function(balance) {
             $('.containerDiv').html(balance);
             //update time, either from server script or by using the client side time
         });

    }, 60000*0.1);
```

Comment: What if I have a div with the id "timestamp" whose value equals to the latest date, how do I set the var to that value?

Comment: If you use jQuery, the best way of doing this would be `$("#myDiv").data("timestamp", myTimeStamp)` - this way, you have no visible markup on the page.

Comment: `var time = document.getElementById('timestamp').value;
       $.get('tableup.php', { lastTime: time }, function(html) {` this part doesn't work for some reason, if I use lastTime: "testvalue" it works.

Comment: is the element with the id timestamp really an input field / hidden field? What does `console.log(time)` reveal?