# Animate Fog / Blur effect in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [foggy Jquery plugin](http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/) to blur text elements on my site. I need a code that can get a number of seconds, and that will animate the blur effect from blurRadius X (see the link) to blurRadius: 1 (means regular text) across the time in seconds that I pass to the function.

So when I call the function and pass the time in seconds, it will animated the fog blur effect. Right now the library support a static effects out of the box. But if we use some type of timer this can animate the effect. I need your help in a code that product this type of animation. Thanks.

I am open to other plugins. However, the Foggy plugin supports fallback for IE (use only opacity), which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long time ago, but here is at least a hint for a simple solution:

```
BlurPass.prototype.render = function(target){
 $('<div/>', {
   html: this.content, 'class': 'foggy-pass-'+this.position
 }).css({
   position: this.position,
   opacity: this.opacity,
   top: this.offset[0],
   left: this.offset[1]
 }).appendTo(target).fadeIn('slow');
};
```

just add **.fadeIn('slow');** to the append-func

see also: [jQuery using append with effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/jquery-using-append-with-effects)