# Applying smoothness in .append()

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to apply `show('slow')` with `.append()` but doesn't seem to work at all. Here is my code:

```
var listing = "html data";

$('#sectionArticles').append(listing);
```

I found we can only use `show('slow')` with `appendTo`, is that true? How to apply smooth loading in this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery using append with effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/jquery-using-append-with-effects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**wrxsti**'s solution works well, but an *alternative* could be to use `fadeIn()`, see link below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wqAjd/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Should work just fine. I have included an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/RZjAu/

Javascript:

```
var listing = "<p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>";

$('#sectionArticles').append(listing).show('slow');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sectionArticles"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sectionArticles {
    display:none;
}
```