# How to add transition to masonry items on init?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

Here is a pen:
https://codepen.io/DTX/pen/xXaBpJ

```
$('#sort').click(() => {
  $('.item').sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5)
    .each((i, el) => $(el).parent().append(el));

  $grid.masonry('destroy')
  $grid.masonry()
})
```

I want to add transition to items like on resizing, when I press Sort button. Can i?
[image]

Comment: What kind of transition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery using append with effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/jquery-using-append-with-effects)

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: If you use isotope, sorting and filtering animations are part of the plugin. Might save you some headaches.