# jQuery animate on previously appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate a div that I previously appended, but the animation doesn't happen, even though the `complete` function is executed.

Here is a very simple example:

**EDIT: I corrected the typo in my jsFiddle and the problem is still there, but thank you for pointing it out.**

**HTML:**

```
<button id="test">
    Go
</button>
<div class="elements">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  $("<div class='element-test'><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:40; top:400px; left:200px; width:2%;'></div>")
  .appendTo('.elements').animate({top:'100px', left:'400px'}, 500, function(){
      $('.element-test').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

I wrote a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqh7u1jv/1/) showing the problem.

In my application, I would need to animate this with % positions, and I thought that was the problem in the beginning. However, changing it to pixel positions or even pure int numbers in the `animate` parameters doesn't solve it.

At the beginning, I was using `.append()` and then `animate()`. The idea of using `appendTo().animate()` comes from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/jquery-using-append-with-effects).

Comment: There is a typo in your posted code... Just [fix it](https://jsfiddle.net/oqh7u1jv/1/) As a side note, each time you click you append a new element

Comment: Thank you, but the animation still won't happen, ie the image is still not moving and that's what I would like to happen.

Comment: You animate the container of image, not image itself. You could use: `.appendTo('.elements').children('img')` but you still have dupe issue on each click

Comment: That's the answer I needed, thank you for that.

Comment: Could be something you are looking for, e.g: [https://jsfiddle.net/oqh7u1jv/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/oqh7u1jv/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You must first wait for the image, until it will be fully loaded, with `onload` event. Then, in callback of `onload` event, you can run the animation:

```js
var $container = $('.elements')
var imageSrc = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png'
var element = `
  <div class="element-test">
    <img src="${imageSrc}">
  </div
`

function appendElement (elm) {
  $(elm).appendTo($container)
  $('.element-test img').on('load', animateElement)
}

function animateElement () {
  $(this)
    .animate({
      top: '+=100',
      left: '+=400'
    }, 1000)
    .promise()
    .then($(this).fadeOut())
}

$('#test').click(appendElement.bind(this, element))
```

```css
.element-test img {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Go</button>
<div class="elements"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery append() function behaves synchronously so there is no need to wait for anything. Your solution actually works because you also solved my problem by animating the image and not the div. That was my problem, as simple as that.

Comment: @Driblou But without waiting for an onload event, you start the animation before it appears.

Comment: In my actual code (not here), I called the animate() function on next line, after append(), and it works perfectly without needing your solution. I think you are right if I call append().animate(), which I did on my original post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in typing:

You used `top:100px'` instead of `top:'100px'`

Here is correct code:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  $("<div class='element-test'><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png' style='position:absolute; z-index:40; top:400px; left:200px; width:2%;'></div>").appendTo('.elements').animate({top:'100px', left:'400px'}, 500, function(){
    $('.element-test').fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

Here is JSBin showing you how to append and animate, adjust your code to it:
http://jsbin.com/wotafijiru/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you, but the animation still won't happen, ie the image is still not moving and that's what I would like to happen.

Comment: Check JSBin I've added

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
  var img = $("<div class='element-test'><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png' style='height:130px;width:130px;position:absolute;'></div>");
  $("body").append(img);
  $('img').animate({
    left: '250px',
    opacity: '0.5',
    top: '+=100px',
    left: '+=400px'
  });
  $('img').fadeOut(200)  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">
  Go
</button>

<div class="elements"></div>
```